# Capturing ANY event that triggers a postback and firing an event before the data is sent to the server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is there a way to capture any event that triggers a postback from my masterpage and show a pageloader until the page has fully loaded?
Clarification, I want the pageloader to show as soon a the button is pushed or a dropdownlist has changed a value.
I currently use this script on my masterpage

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //it just changes style of body to display:block hiding an existing pageloader
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
});
```

But what happens with this code is that as soon as I fire a postback the page might take 5 to 10 seconds to load (awaits server to respond with data from sql) and only afterwards will it trigger the javascript event.

Here is a dropdownlist that triggers a postback that is inside the `ContentPlaceHolder` of the masterpage:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSubproject" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDDLSprj" 
        DataTextField="SubProject" DataValueField="SubProjectID" CssClass="TextBox" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Subproject..." Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You can use updatepanel with updateprogress like the following msdn article  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by JKOU, I used an UpdatePanel in my MasterPage and enclosed my ContentPlaceHolder within the ContentTemplate of the UpdatePanel. At the same time at the UpdateProgress Template I enclosed my preloader.It all works well without javascript.

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
               <Triggers> 
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MainContent" /> 
               </Triggers>                                     
               <ContentTemplate> 
                    <div class="main">       
                        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>                                   
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>   
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button ID="hiddenAsyncTrigger" runat="server" Text="AsyncUpdate" style="display:none;" />
               </ContentTemplate>                                  
            </asp:UpdatePanel>    
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"> 
                <ProgressTemplate > 
                    <div id="loader-wrapper"> //My PageLoader animation
                        <div id="loader"></div>
                        <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
                        <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate> 
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

This way, any postback triggered within the page first animates my Page Loader and then stops when page is loaded.